# Why are watchers not firing when ui-router state data is changed on parent?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am unable to get a `$scope.$watch` or `$scope.$watchCollection` to trigger when updating `$state.current.data` from a parent view.

I've created a plunker to demonstrate: http://plnkr.co/edit/d4hblq9QvnMOLQKxO9jc?p=preview
To use, navigate to the `/main/1` path and click the 'change' button. You will see the `$state.data` get updated, yet the watchers never get a notification.

Here is the `script.js` source:

```
var app = angular
  .module('MyApp', [
    'ui.router'
  ])
  .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main');
      $stateProvider
      // States
       .state("main", {
          data: {hello:'hello'},
          controller:'mainController',
          url:"/main",
          templateUrl: "main_init.html"
        })  
      .state("main.1", {
        controller:'childController',
        parent: 'main',
        url:"/1",
        templateUrl: 'form_1.html'
    })  
  }])
  .controller('mainController', function ($scope, $state, $timeout) {
    $scope.Model = $scope.Model || {Name : "xxx"};
    $scope.changeHello = function changeHello(){
      console.log('about to change...');
      $timeout(function(){
        $state.current.data.hello = 'hi';
        console.log('changed.');
      },3500);
    }
  })
.controller('childController', function($scope, $state, $timeout){
  $scope.changeStatus = 'nothing yet';
  $scope.$watch($state.$current.data.hello, function(newObj){
    if(newObj){
      console.log('changed');
      $scope.changeStatus = 'changed via watch';
    }
  });
  $scope.$watchCollection($state.$current.data, function(newObj){
    if(newObj){
      console.log('changed');
      $scope.changeStatus = 'changed via watchcollection';
    }
  });
  $scope.$watchCollection($state.$current, function(newObj){
    if(newObj){
      console.log('changed');
      $scope.changeStatus = 'changed via watchcollection $current';
    }
  });
  $scope.$watchCollection($state.current, function(newObj){
    if(newObj){
      console.log('changed');
      $scope.changeStatus = 'changed via watchcollection current';
    }
  });
})
app.run(
    ['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
      function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
          $rootScope.$state = $state;
          $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
      }
    ])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$watch` is looking for an event that is the value of your variable, `$state.current.data.hello`. This is what it's doing:

`$scope.$watch('hello', function(newObj)...`

Put your variable in quotes and the `$watch` will work as expected:

`$scope.$watch('$state.current.data.hello', function(newObj)...`

Comment: Ah, thanks! I had forgotten about putting quotes around object names on `$watch` commands.

Comment: I wonder how this can work (anyway, it doesn't here). $state is not on the scope! To make it work, I had to define a function that returns the data to be watched, and then watch the function result.